# How to check two structs for equality

Tags: go

I have two instances of this struct with references inside (as properties):

```
type ST struct {
 some *float64
 createdAt *time.Time
}
```

How can I preform a check for equality for two different instances of this struct? Is it only by using reflect?

Answer (score 3):

While you could use reflection, [as Corey Ogburn suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52670446/1964690), I would not do so for a simple struct like that.  Per the official Go Blog, reflection is

> a powerful tool that should be used with care and avoided unless strictly necessary

-- [The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

It should be a simple exercise for you to write a function that takes two pointers to values of your struct type and returns a boolean true/false as to whether they are equal, first by testing for nil pointers and then by testing for equality of each of the fields of the struct.

`time.Time` values already have [an equality test method](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal) with signature

```
func (t Time) Equal(u Time) bool
```

Depending on your use cases, the bigger problem may be comparing two floating point values for equality.  While `==` comparisons [work](https://play.golang.org/p/BDCk3GrTvvE) on `float64` values, for many applications you want two float values to be considered equal when they are close, as well as when they are exactly the same.  If that is the case for your application, I recommend defining an equal function that accepts a precision and verifies that the difference between the two values is not greater than the precision.  To learn more, research floating point representations of decimal values.

Note that `time` package documentation has this to [say](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) about using pointers:

> Programs using times should typically store and pass them as values, not pointers. That is, time variables and struct fields should be of type time.Time, not *time.Time.

So you should probably change the type of `createdAt` in your struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflect.DeepEqual](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).

> DeepEqual reports whether x and y are “deeply equal,” defined as follows. Two values of identical type are deeply equal if one of the following cases applies. Values of distinct types are never deeply equal.

The documentation then goes on to describe how arrays, structs, functions, pointers and other types are considered to be deeply equal.

Comment: So what does it means, pointers will be checked by values that they are pointing to or their references?

Comment: According to the docs: `Pointer values are deeply equal if they are equal using Go's == operator or if they point to deeply equal values.` It sounds like it will check first if they point to the same thing, if they do, they're equal. If the pointers point to different things, the 2 pointed objects will be compared using DeepEqual.